# cucumber test for ruby-1.9.2 and mongoid-2.0.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, cucumber, bdd, mongoid, ruby-1.9.2

I am having a really hard time. I am using cucumber tests for visiting a link. I am using the pickle web steps for

```
When I go to the post comment's new page
```

It does not seem to be working. I also tried `I am on the post comment's new page` but that is also not working. The error is `stack level too deep`. However when I write the custom step of my own the test is passing. It is too tiresome to write the steps for every page. Is anyone else getting a similar problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've seen the exact same error but managed to get rid of it by replacing the following auto-generated pickle path helper in `features/step_definitions/paths.rb`

```
when /^#{capture_model}(?:'s)? (.+?) page$/
  path_to_pickle $1, :extra => $2
```

with my own:

```
when /^#{capture_model}(?:'s)? (.+?) page$/
  polymorphic_path(model($1), :action => $2)
```

Comment: okay... but what I wanted to do is use the steps of pickle itself. Is there any way I won't have to write my custom steps? If i replace path_to_pickle with  polymorphic_path will there be any problem? and what about nested routes?

Comment: How to write polymorphic_path for "post's comment's new page". I tried "polymorphic_path(model($1, $2), :action => $3)", but there was "wrong number of arguments" error. Also comment is new it will give "undefined method `model_name' for NilClass:Class" error.

Comment: Something like `polymorphic_path(model!($1), model!($2), :action => $3)` should work. I'd use the bang model method to make sure the model exists to avoid passing invalid arguments to `polymorphic_path`.

Answer (score 2):

I simply replaced:

```
path_to_pickle $1, :extra => $2
```

With:

```
path_to_pickle $1, :action => $2
```